# How do I grep a directories permissions and see if it lacks write permissions?

Tags: files, permissions

I am trying to write a script that runs on boot that checks to see if the boot filesystem is read only, if it is, then run `fsck` to fix permissions and reboot.

Point 1: I am having trouble figuring out how to grep just the permissions line from a `ls` command.

Point 2: I am also having trouble figuring out how to check if that command returns a string without `w` in it.

For example, an ls -l command returns a line similar to the following:

`drwx-----+    5 Admin  staff   170 Oct 12 05:41 Documents`

I want to grab just the following string:

`drwx-----+`

Then, check if it does not contain write permissions.

Below is the script I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

$DIR='home'

#If $DIR has only read permissions run loop
if [[ #point 1 = #point 2 ]] then
    #fix permissions on $DIR
    umount ${DIR}
    fsck
    reboot
fi
```

Comment: It's easy to do what you want : if  ls -l dir | awk '{print $1}'|grep w; then ... but it makes totally no reason to do that in such compilated and resourse-consuming way.

Comment: @gena2x Thanks for your comment, however, is there a way to check if a single directory contains write permissions? That command returns the permissions of each directory within the directory I specified.

Comment: Why do you parse `ls` output? The shell has some native features to test permissions of files (from the callers point of view); alternatively, there is the `stat` command. Or you may use the `find` command with a suitable search expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ever parse the output of **ls**. Scripting 101.

```
man find
man findmnt
```

The root file system is never mounted read-only if the system has reached the multiuser target or runlevel. This means that the only user who can ever find the root file system mounted read-only is root. And root can write everywhere regardless of permissions. Therefore, to check whether the root filesystem is readonly you can simply try to touch a file:

```
if touch /testfile ; then
# The root filesystem is read-write
  rm /testfile
else
# The root filesystem is read-only
# Do something about it
fi
```

However, this should not be needed. The system should drop into a single-user shell if it cannot mount the root file system read-write.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ! [[ -w "$DIR" ]]; then
    # $DIR is not writeable
fi
```

This will apply *for the current user* though. Don't know if that's what you want.

EDIT: If you do need to extract the permissions string, a simple way is by using stat:

```
stat -c %A "$DIR"
```

returns something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Comment: _is not writeable_... **by the caller**. Here, the caller is most likely root, so will have write access as long as the filesystem is not mounted read-only regardless of the permissions.

Comment: See my edit just now.